# cannot import name 'configure_inline_support

Tags: python, matplotlib

I install matplotlib package with conda and then try to run below code with jupyter notebook:

```
from pylab import plt, mpl
plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
%matplotlib inline
```

Unfortunately i got below error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'configure_inline_support' from 'ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
```

Also checked and ipykernel is also installed.

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: code works for me on Jupyter Notebook - Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8. Did you check in Google `cannot import name 'configure_inline_support' from 'ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'` ?  Maybe it need to install some more. If you have full error message with number of line which makes problem then you could check source code to see what it tried to use before this line.

Comment: did you try to use `%matplotlib inline` before other elements? Or `%matplotlib` before `%matplotlib inline` ?

Comment: I reproduced this problem with fresh installed `Jupyter Notebook` on `Python 3.9` but after (re)installing  `matplotlib` (update to newest 3.4.1) it dissaperd. Now I have new problem with some `kiwisolver` :) Powodzenia.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced problem with fresh installed `Jupyter Notebook` on `Python 3.9` on `Linux Mint`.

After updating `matplotlib` (to newest `3.4.1`) it dissaperd.

```
sudo python3.9 -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

---

Next I had problem with some `kiwisolver`.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kiwisolver'
```

But updating it (to newest `1.3.1`) resolved this problem.

```
sudo python3.9 -m pip install -U kiwisolver
```

---

Now it works for me.